# ERROR running force:org:create: Unrecognized option: cookiesAllowAllPaths

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-error

When trying to create a scratch org via SFDX in vsCode, I am getting the following error:

`ERROR running force:org:create: Unrecognized option: cookiesAllowAllPaths`

I wish I could give more context as to what was causing this, but all I have currently is this:

The sfdx cli update 7.130 messed with our current org set up and I was unable to build a scratch org or push data to any scratch orgs from vsCode due to an entirely different error. So, I uninstalled npm and sfdx cli entirely and reinstalled with an earlier version of sfdx cli (7.96.1) via npm. I am now able to pull and push data to scratch orgs via sfdx cli, but when I go to create a scratch org, I am now getting the above error.

Has anyone run into an error like this and know where to look to resolve it?

Comment: This has been [reported](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1323) as an issue, but seems to possibly be related to an older version. Have you tried updating to the latest version? Do you have any extra plugins installed? What OS are you using? The more info we have, the better we might be able to assist you.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for the link to that thread. Unfortunately, the latest version may be causing issues when it comes to building and pushing to scratch orgs as we get an error relating to our **\lwc\jsconfig.js files (despite having it listed in our .forceignore). So, I was hoping rolling back to a version recommended by our lead dev would potentially resolve THAT error. But, looks like this may be unlucky timing to attempt that with this issue just popping up recently. No other plugins installed, and using Windows.